# Do No-Load Trimpot Exists

Tags: potentiometer

No-load potentiometers exists - they take themselves out of the circuit when turned all the way up.

I've been looking at a number of sites - Aliexpress and others, to find no-load trimpots.

But, I've not been able to. Do no-load trimpots exists?

I'm not concerned if they're SMD or not for now.

Comment: Isn't that every pot? ~0Ohms when turned all the way down and max Ohms when turned all the way up.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think they're talking about the kind with an integrated switch. (and it's worth noting that most pots have a minimum resistance a fair bit higher than you'd think!)

Comment: Like one of those pots with a detent and an off switch? But an on switch instead of an off switch? Can't say I've ever seen those. The ones with an off-switch are difficult to find as it is. And if it exists, I think it would be astonishing behaviour to suddenly go to 0Ohms when the pot is turned all the way UP (to max resistance).

Comment: I've never even seen an audio-taper trimpot, and I've really looked hard.  I doubt there are no-load trimpots.   To answer others who have no idea what you're talking about --- No-load pots are a real thing.  Move the wiper far enough, it breaks contact with the track and goes open circuit.    I've only ever seen them in panel-mount versions - specifically for electric guitar pots, where the player wants to take the pots effect out of the circuit altogether.   i.e.  https://shop.fender.com/en-US/parts/controls-switches/250k-no-load-split-shaft-potentiometer/0990832000.html

Comment: Oh, when the OP says "they take themselves out of the circuit" they mean the pot goes open? I had interpreted "a resistor that takes itself out of the circuit" to mean 0Ohms. Those definitely exist, but I've also never seen one as a trimpot. Use a jumper.